# Passing String from C# to C++ DLL different Text Encoding on different return Types

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, dllexport

I hope somebody can explain what exactly the difference is:

In my C# Programm I want to pass an String to an C++ Method.
My Code in C# looks like this:

```
    [DllImport("Test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern String DoIt(String filename);
```

The inside of my C++ DLL looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) CString DoIt(char* szFilename)
{
....
}
```

If I pass the String (like: C:\temp\my.txt) it becomes malformed =>"Ôœ&°8é-".

Now comes the confusings part I can't literly understand. If I change the return Type from CString to char* everything is fine.

```
__declspec( dllexport ) char* DoIt(char* filename)
```

Why is that so? The CharSet in C# is already set to Ansi to Marshal the String into the right Type. I cannot figure out where the connection between the return Type and my passing String is.

If you need more information just let me know.

Comment: where is it malformed? Output window, logfile, watch window?

Comment: I discovered the malformation when i debugged the DLL. When I hover over the argument "filename" or using an AfxMessageBox() it is displayed as malformed.

Comment: CString is a C++ class, pinvoke does not support C++ specific types at all.  char* is a workaround of sorts, but still has a memory-management problem.  Consider returning a BSTR.  You need SysAllocString() in the C++ code and [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] to let the CLR know about it.

Comment: Hey Hans, i will give it a try and test it. But why is it influencing the argument?

Comment: The function is returning the CString object by value.  That requires the caller to reserve space for the value, it passes a pointer to that space.  None of this happens when the call is made from C#, the pointer is missing and that throws off the arguments as well.

Comment: The last comment from David Heffernan is quite the answere i was looking for, because the malformation occurs when i pass the String from C# to C++ (parameter `filename` not the return Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions of your code are wrong. You certainly can't pass `CString` as an interop type. You to use simple types for interop, not C++ classes.

The error when you use `char*` is more subtle. In that scenario there are two problems.

Firstly, with a `string` return type on the C# side, the pinvoke marshaller assumes that the returned string was allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc` and will call `CoTaskMemFree` to deallocate it once it has been copied.

Secondly, although we can't see it, your C++ code almost certainly returns a pointer to a buffer owned by a local variable in the C++ function. Obviously this local variable goes out of scope when the function returns and so the pointer becomes invalid.

Some options:

1. Have the caller locate the string buffer and let the callee populate it.
2. Allocate the returned `char*` using `CoTaskMemAlloc` and so meet the expectations of the C# code.
3. Use the COM `BSTR` type which the pinvoke marshaller does understand.

Comment: In short because of the wrong usage of string as an return type in C# the pinvoke marshaller malformes the argument inside the memory? I mainly dont care about the return type but more for the argument i pass from C# to C++.

Comment: No. The malformed text comes from using `CString` which does not match `string` on the C# side

Comment: So the `CString` in C++ and `string` in C# is causing the malformation of the passing String from C# to C++? Even if the argument type is still the same?

Comment: Pinvoke marshaler can't marshall a C++ type like `CString` at all. That's the first paragraph in my answer. Don't know what you mean by "argument type is still the same"

Comment: With the argument is meant `filename` the parameter I am giving the Method to do something. The type is still char* from the beginning. But that's the value who gets malformed.

Comment: OK well that's probably because using CString in the C++ code changes the way the parameters are passed and so the input param is passed in a way differently from how the callee expects.